# How to modify this CSS based Accordion to work with multiple accordions on the same page?

Tags: html, css

Hello I have am using an accordion off a website: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-content-accordion/ created by Paul Underwood. I love the accordion as it looks great with simple css. The only issue however that I want a few separate ones on the same page. This ruins the functionality since their all the same class. Is there any way besides copying and pasting and renaming everything about the class as many times as needed so that they'd all have their own class? Again the overall goal is to have a few of these work on the same page.

Here is the code directly off his website:

Html:

```
 <div class="accordion vertical">  
 <section>  
      <h2>About Us</h2>  
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>  
  </section>  

<section>  
    <h2>Services</h2>  
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>  
</section>  

<section>  
    <h2>Blog</h2>  
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>  
</section>  

<section>  
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>  
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>  
</section>  

<section>  
    <h2>Contact</h2>  
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>  
</section>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/**
 *  CSS3 Only Horizontal and Vertical Accordion
 *  Author: Paul Underwood for Hongkiat.com
 *  Website: www.paulund.co.uk
 *  Date: 27/11/11
 *  Version: 1.0
 */


article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { display: block; }
audio, canvas, video { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
[hidden] { display: none; }
html { font-size: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.231; }
body, button, input, select, textarea { font-family: sans-serif; color: #222; }

/*Define Accordion box*/
.accordion { width:830px; overflow:hidden; margin:10px auto; color:#474747; background:#414141; padding:10px; }

/*General Accordion****************************************************************************/
/*Set style of open slide*/
.accordion section:target { background:#FFF; padding:10px;}
.accordion section:target:hover { background:#FFF; }
.accordion section:target h2 {width:100%;}
.accordion section:target h2 a{ color:#333; padding:0;}
.accordion section:target p {display:block;}
.accordion section h2 a{padding:8px 10px;display:block; font-size:16px; font-weight:normal;color:#eee; text-decoration:none; }

/*set style of closed slide*/
.accordion section{ float:left; overflow:hidden; color:#333; cursor:pointer; background: #333; margin:3px; }
.accordion section:hover {background:#444;}
.accordion section p { display:none; }
.accordion section:after{position:relative;font-size:24px;color:#000;font-weight:bold;}
.accordion section:nth-child(1):after{content:'1';}
.accordion section:nth-child(2):after{content:'2';}
.accordion section:nth-child(3):after{content:'3';}
.accordion section:nth-child(4):after{content:'4';}
.accordion section:nth-child(5):after{content:'5';}
/*End General     Accordion****************************************************************************/

/*Horizontal Accordion *********************************************************************/
.horizontal section{ width:5%; height:250px; 
-moz-transition:width 0.2s ease-out; 
-webkit-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
-ms-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
}

/*Position the number of the slide*/
.horizontal section:after{top:140px;left:15px;}

/*Header of closed slide*/
.horizontal section h2 { 
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
width:240px; position:relative; left:-100px; top:85px;
} 

/*On mouse over open slide*/
.horizontal :target{ width:73%;height:230px; }
.horizontal :target h2{ top:0px;left:0;
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg); 
}
/*End Horizontal Accordion *********************************************************************/

/*Vertical Accordion *************************************************************************/
.vertical section{ width:100%; height:40px;
-webkit-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
-ms-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
}
/*Set height of the slide*/
.vertical :target{ height:250px; width:97%; }

.vertical section h2 { position:relative; left:0; top:-15px; }

/*Set position of the number on the slide*/
.vertical section:after{ top:-60px;left:810px;}
.vertical section:target:after{ left:-9999px;}
```

Comment: You need to change the formatting of the beginning of the div in the HTML block so it shows in the code window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No CSS changes are necessary. You should just be able to change the names of the ids and targets in the HTML for a new table, e.g.

```
    <div class="accordion vertical">
      <section id="foo">
          <h2><a href="#foo">Foo</a></h2>
          <!-- content -->
          <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      </section>
    </div>
```

etc ...